# How to create a dll of a user define form in C# VS2010

Tags: c#, forms, file, dll, client

I have to created a dll file of my own Form using c# in VS 2010, but I am not able to embed some functionality like. When Client form minimize my form visible should be false.
When Client form size change then my form size should also change according to it.

It's look and feel should be like, my form is a part of client form.

Comment: A little clearer question would be easier. Is your Form a new windowed Form in your application, or is your dll a UserControl library and your 'form' actually a Control like a Panel inserted into the actual Form.

If the first then you will need to capture Minimise/Maximise and resize events in the First form and apply the desired Properties to your form. If the second is true then Visible does not apply, 'OnScreen' I think is a valid alternative, and your control should be dockable and anchor-able to the parent form/control

Comment: i have created a form which have one textbox having multiline true and form border none. Now i want to use this form in Microsoft Navision as a text box because Navision does not support multi line text box. I want this form should be visible on Navision form just like a navision control. So meet this need i have created a dll for the same. Pls help Thanks in advance

Comment: I have no idea what Navision is.

Comment: Very quick Googleing tells me that TextBoxes in Navision have a multiline property - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/dd301445.aspx

Comment: Yes textbox in Navision have multiline property but it is not same as text box in .Net. If we press enter in text box of navision cursor dose not goes on next line but it moves to next control. :(

Comment: Shift Enter is not working

Comment: Then I'm out of ideas.